# How to use create_association in ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am having trouble getting the create_association(attributes = {}) method to work for associated models in Rails.

```
class Gwgiftwhip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :gift, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :gift, :presence => true  
end

class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gwgiftwhip
end
```

The [belongs_to section in the Active Record Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference) suggests that you should be able to use the method: create_association(attributes = {}) to create a related model and save it when using the belongs_to association.  However, the below implementation results in a save error due to the related model parameter, 'gift' not being set.

```
class GiftsController < ApplicationController
...
def inbound
  @gift = Gift.new(params.slice(*Gift.new.acceptable))    
  if @gift.create_gwgiftwhip({:user_id => @gift.user_id}, :without_protection => true)
    ...
  end
end
```

The below works, but seems like it's outside the intended use.  It is creating a related model, then setting itself as the related model.  This requires another step to then save.

```
class GiftsController < ApplicationController
...
def inbound
  @gift = Gift.new(params.slice(*Gift.new.acceptable))    
  @gift.create_gwgiftwhip({:user_id => @gift.user_id}, :without_protection => true).gift = @gift
  if @gift.gwgiftwhip.save
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning it around:

```
def inbound
  @gift = Gift.new( params.slice( *Gift.new.acceptable ) )    
  if Gwgiftwhip.create( {user_id: @gift.user_id, 
                            gift: @gift}, without_protection: true )
    ...
  end
end
```

You might also conisder overriding `gift=` on Gwgiftwhip so that setting `gift` sets `user_id` automatically.  Example:

```
class Gwgiftwhip
  has_one :gift, :autosave => true, :dependent => :destroy

  def gift=( gift )
    super( gift )
    self.user_id = gift.user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like .create() is going to return the new object regardless of validations passing, so actually adding (not)new_record? is one way to get that to work `!Gwgiftwhip.create({:user_id => @gift.user_id, :gift => @gift}, :without_protection => true).new_record?`

Comment: Also, great suggestion on overriding the setter method for related model.  It works really well.  For every other use case the user_id needs to be the current_user, so I will probably make use of your suggestion elsewhere.